# weak star convergence of functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $T_n(f)= n\int_{0}^{1/n}f(t)dt$ , $f \in C[0,1] $
I want to show that this converges weak star. I believe that weak star convergence is just pointwise convergence of the functional. This is clearly a functional since we're taking in functions and getting elements of the field back out. It is linear and looks continuous.

I want to show that $T_n(f)  \to T(f)$ converges weak star but not in norm.
I'm thinking that if we can show continuity then weak star convergence can be achieved? I know the norm in question is the infinity norm but not sure how to use it to show that there is no convergence in this sup norm.

Comment: Try to show that $T_n$ converges weak star to $T: C[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $Tf := T(0)$.

Comment: $|T_n(f)-T(f)| \le n \int_{0}^{1/n}|f(t)-0|dt$ which can be made less than epsilon if f(t)-0 is less than epsilon/n

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: but what guarantees than f(t)-0=f(t) can be made that small. what about convergence in norm?

Comment: Uniform continuity of $f$ guarantees this. About convergence in norm i might have to think a bit longer...

Comment: but uniform continuity would apply if $|t-0|=t < \delta$. Is it basically that the interval $[0,1/n]$ a kinda neighborhood (to the right)of 0 with distance at most $1/n$ which we can call our $\delta$ ?

Comment: This is ecactly it

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks. So why did we(you) pick Tf to be f(0)? What was the rationale behind that.

Comment: For the most part, this is experience. But there is also some intuition behind it: By the mean value theorem there exists some $\xi \in \left[0, \frac{1}{n}\right]$ such that $n \int^{\frac{1}{n}}_0 f(t)~\mathrm{d}t = f(\xi)$. What happens when $n$ goes to infinity?

Answer (score 1):

For weak-star-convergence, let $T: C[0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $Tf := f(0)$. Then, for each $f \in C[0, 1]$:
$$
\lvert T_nf - Tf \rvert = \left \lvert n \int^{\frac{1}{n}}_0 f(t) - f(0) ~\mathrm{d}t \right \rvert \leq \sup_{x \in \left[0, \frac{1}{n} \right]} \lvert f(x) - f(0) \rvert \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}0
$$
This holds because $f$ is uniformly continuous on compact intervals. But this is also weak-star-convergence.

The series $T_n$ does not converge to $T$ in the operator norm. Note that $T$ is the only possible limit, because norm-convergence implies weak-star-convergence. We furthermore know that weak-star-limits are unique.

Now let $f_n: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f_n(t) := t^{\frac{1}{n}}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Obviously, $\lVert f_n \rVert_{\infty} = 1$. So:
$$
\lVert T_n - T \rVert = \sup_{\lVert f \rVert_{\infty} = 1} \lvert T_n f - Tf \rvert \geq \lvert T_nf_n - Tf_n \rvert = \left \lvert n \int^{\frac{1}{n}}_0 t^\frac{1}{n}~\mathrm{d}t \right \rvert = \frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{n}} \cdot  \frac{n}{n+1} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}1
$$
This means that convergence in the operator norm is impossible.

By the way: $T_n$ are linear functionals. The infinity norm belongs to $C[0, 1]$. So convergence of $T_n$ in the infinity norm is not interesting in this particular case.

Comment: $\lvert T_nf_n - Tf_n \rvert = \left \lvert n \int^{\frac{1}{n}}_0 t^\frac{1}{n}~\mathrm{d}t \right \rvert$ why is that true? Also can you talk about your thought process here? Thanks

Comment: The formula you stated is true because $Tf_n = f_n(0) = 0$. My thought process was that we have to find some functions $f_n$ with infinity-norm $1$ (and $f_n(0) = 0$ for the sake of simplicity) sucht that $\lvert T_nf_n$ does not tend to zero. So I looked for functions that converge to $1$ pointwise almost everywhere. So there is hope that the integral converges to $1$, too. And this is what in fact happened...